# Convert a namedtuple into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, namedtuple

I have a named tuple class in python

```
class Town(collections.namedtuple('Town', [
    'name', 
    'population',
    'coordinates',
    'population', 
    'capital', 
    'state_bird'])):
    # ...
```

I'd like to convert Town instances into dictionaries. I don't want it to be rigidly tied to the names or number of the fields in a Town.

Is there a way to write it such that I could add more fields, or pass an entirely different named tuple in and get a dictionary.

I can not alter the original class definition as its in someone else's code. So I need to take an instance of a Town and convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: btw... look at tab completion or the `dir` command, which will show you the fields for any object... that would have shown the `_asdict` function directly.

Comment: it looks like what you _really_ want to do is subclass from `dict` instead of 'namedtuple', and pass the namedtuple into the initializer. Remember that if you're used to Cxx, `class Town(x)` isn't the constructor, `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` inside it is.

Comment: I can not alter the original class as its in someone elses code. so I have to subclass from namedtouble

Comment: @CorleyBrigman can you explain this more? I tried to find documentation on the named touple, or find what I could call on it and I couldnt figure out how. (Again python is not my strongest language)

Comment: which part? `dir` is just a python built-in... you can run it on _any_ python object, in a console or in a script (where it returns a list you can print or do whatever with), and it will return a list of (nearly) all the attributes the object. helpful if you're trying to figure out how an unknown object works.

Comment: I had no idea, thats is incredibly helpful. My biggest struggle with python is the lack of API documentation. I never know what I can do with objects, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: For going the other way (dictionary into namedtuple), look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43921240/674039

Answer (score 414, accepted):

*TL;DR: there's a method `_asdict` provided for this.*

Here is a demonstration of the usage:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> fields = ['name', 'population', 'coordinates', 'capital', 'state_bird']
>>> Town = namedtuple('Town', fields)
>>> funkytown = Town('funky', 300, 'somewhere', 'lipps', 'chicken')
>>> funkytown._asdict()
{'name': 'funky',
 'population': 300,
 'coordinates': 'somewhere',
 'capital': 'lipps',
 'state_bird': 'chicken'}
```

This is a [documented method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) of namedtuples, i.e. unlike the usual convention in python **the leading underscore on the method name isn't there to discourage use**.  Along with the other methods added to namedtuples, `_make`, `_replace`, `_source`, `_fields`, it has the underscore only to try and prevent conflicts with possible field names.

---

*Note:*  For some 2.7.5 < python version < 3.5.0 code out in the wild, you might see this version:

```
>>> vars(funkytown)
OrderedDict([('name', 'funky'),
             ('population', 300),
             ('coordinates', 'somewhere'),
             ('capital', 'lipps'),
             ('state_bird', 'chicken')])
```

For a while the documentation had mentioned that `_asdict` was obsolete (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict)), and suggested to use the built-in method [vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars).  That advice is now outdated; in order to fix [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue24931) related to subclassing, the `__dict__` property which was present on namedtuples has again been removed by [this commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/fa3ac31cfa44).

Comment: Does anyone know if there an established precedent that suggests `_asdict` shouldn't be aliased in the standard library to `asdict`?

Comment: @KobeJohn then you couldn't have `"asdict"` be one of the tuple names.

Comment: infuriating! `vars` is the natural, idiomatic way to do this! Could it not handle namedtuple as a special case? Doesn't seem to me like it would be tooo hard

Comment: @robert  `vars(obj)` is supposed to be equivalent to `obj.__dict__`, so the special-case would be changing the documented behavior of `vars` (tuple instances don't carry around a `__dict__`)

Comment: yes, I understand the excuse, but it doesn't cut any ice with me. What you are describing is how it is implemented, and `vars`  "hides" that implementation (to use the OO parlance). I guess there's probably a "good" reason why they couldn't simply overload the method, but to me it seems like a slip in standards.

Comment: As of 3.8, `_asdict()` returns a `dict` and not an `OrderedDict` since as of version 3.7, `dict`s are ordered.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 35):

There's a built in method on `namedtuple` instances for this, [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict).

As discussed in the comments, on some versions `vars()` will also do it, but it's apparently highly dependent on build details, whereas `_asdict` should be reliable. In some versions `_asdict` was marked as deprecated, but comments indicate that this is no longer the case as of 3.4.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but it could be because the `_asdict` method has been [obsoleted in python3 (in favour of vars)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict)

Comment: Conversely, it looks like `vars` does't work on some older versions - on 2.7 it raises a `TypeError`, since that version's `namedtuple` class does not have an `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: yes, Martijn and I have discussed that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19840533/674039).  It will work on newer versions of 2.7 btw (I'm on 2.7.6 and it works)

Comment: Past the edit window on my above comment - it fails on 2.7.5 so it must be new as of 2.7.6. Unless my 2.7.5 build is off, as Martijn's was at the linked answer? Anyway, it seems like whether or not it works on 2.7.5 depends on build specifics.

Comment: Just a heads up: _asdict is not longer obseleted (and returns an OrderedDict now), and vars produces an error with Python 3.4 (from the removal of the __dict__ attribute of namedtuples).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - thanks, updated the answer with that information. Looks like `_asdict` is the most consistent way to do it, even if it was deprecated in some versions.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh That's inaccurate, it's still working in python 3.5.0.

Comment: @wim, I said in 3.4. The `__dict__` magic method has been removed and inserted many times in various Python versions. The class does have it, however, the instance does not, meaning vars will not **reliably** work.

_asdict was once deprecated, however, it is no longer and works in recent 2.7.x and 3.2+ versions, meaning it is the most reliable way to convert namedtuples to a mapping structure.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  But it is plainly incorrect that `vars()` is no longer working in 3.4 (as OP has edited into the answer).  [Online python 3.4 example of it working here](https://ideone.com/gk6Kmj).

Comment: I can't keep track of the apparently often-changing state of `vars()`. Open to suggestions for how else to accurately describe it.

Comment: So I just tested it on 5 different builds. 3.4.3+ on Ubuntu (GCC 5.2.1, installed via apt-get) fails, 3.5.1 on Ubuntu (GCC 5.2.1, installed via makefile) fails, Windows 3.4.1 installed by MSI succeeds, it works on Python 3.3.6 (GCC 5.2.1, Ubuntu, makefile), and works on Python 3.2.6 (Ubuntu, GCC 5.2.1, makefile).

I would say it does **not** work fairly reliably, and that should be a key point. Python is meant to be **portable**, if it fails on half of all CPython builds, that's a very low standard for portability.

This is why I say use _asdict. It's reliable.

Comment: On all of the above, `_asdict` works. I get that this is highly build dependent, but considering that `_asdict` works, reliably, and also that `__dict__` in Python3.x is just a property of `_asdict` in the Python3.3 and Python3.2 methods (looked manually at the source code in collections/__init__.py).

Since `__dict__` just is a property of `_asdict`, and is intermittently present and missing, shouldn't `_asdict` be the preferred method?

(Line 274 in Python3.3.6, collections/__init__.py)

Answer (score 9):

Normally `_asdict()` returns a `OrderedDict`. this is how to convert from `OrderedDict` to a regular `dict`

```py
town = Town('funky', 300, 'somewhere', 'lipps', 'chicken')
dict(town._asdict())
```

the output will be

```
{'capital': 'lipps',
 'coordinates': 'somewhere',
 'name': 'funky',
 'population': 300,
 'state_bird': 'chicken'}
```

Comment: This is no longer necessary.  As of Python 3.8, `_asdict()` returns a `dict` and not an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS versions of python2.7 and python3.4 the `__dict__` property worked as expected. The `_asdict` *method* also worked, but I'm inclined to use the standards-defined, uniform, property api instead of the localized non-uniform api.

$ python2.7

```
# Works on:
# Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)  [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
# Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)  [GCC 4.8.4] on linux

import collections

Color = collections.namedtuple('Color', ['r', 'g', 'b'])
red = Color(r=256, g=0, b=0)

# Access the namedtuple as a dict
print(red.__dict__['r'])  # 256

# Drop the namedtuple only keeping the dict
red = red.__dict__
print(red['r'])  #256
```

Seeing as **dict** is the semantic way to get a dictionary representing soemthing, (at least to the best of my knowledge).

---

It would be nice to accumulate a table of major python versions and platforms and their support for `__dict__`, currently I only have one platform version and two python versions as posted above.

```
| Platform                      | PyVer     | __dict__ | _asdict |
| --------------------------    | --------- | -------- | ------- |
| Ubuntu 14.04 LTS              | Python2.7 | yes      | yes     |
| Ubuntu 14.04 LTS              | Python3.4 | yes      | yes     |
| CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 | Python2.7 | no       | yes     |
| CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 | Python3.4 | no       | yes     |
| CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 | Python3.6 | no       | yes     |
```

Comment: Linux-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.4.1708-Core, Python 2.7 -- `__dict__` does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Case #1: one dimension tuple

```
TUPLE_ROLES = (
    (912,"Role 21"),
    (913,"Role 22"),
    (925,"Role 23"),
    (918,"Role 24"),
)


TUPLE_ROLES[912]  #==> Error because it is out of bounce. 
TUPLE_ROLES[  2]  #==> will show Role 23.
DICT1_ROLE = {k:v for k, v in TUPLE_ROLES }
DICT1_ROLE[925] # will display "Role 23"
```

Case #2: Two dimension tuple
Example: DICT_ROLES[961] # will show 'Back-End Programmer'

```
NAMEDTUPLE_ROLES = (
    ('Company', ( 
            ( 111, 'Owner/CEO/President'), 
            ( 113, 'Manager'),
            ( 115, 'Receptionist'),
            ( 117, 'Marketer'),
            ( 119, 'Sales Person'),
            ( 121, 'Accountant'),
            ( 123, 'Director'),
            ( 125, 'Vice President'),
            ( 127, 'HR Specialist'),
            ( 141, 'System Operator'),
    )),
    ('Restaurant', ( 
            ( 211, 'Chef'), 
            ( 212, 'Waiter/Waitress'), 
    )),
    ('Oil Collector', ( 
            ( 211, 'Truck Driver'), 
            ( 213, 'Tank Installer'), 
            ( 217, 'Welder'),
            ( 218, 'In-house Handler'),
            ( 219, 'Dispatcher'),
    )),
    ('Information Technology', ( 
            ( 912, 'Server Administrator'),
            ( 914, 'Graphic Designer'),
            ( 916, 'Project Manager'),
            ( 918, 'Consultant'),
            ( 921, 'Business Logic Analyzer'),
            ( 923, 'Data Model Designer'),
            ( 951, 'Programmer'),
            ( 953, 'WEB Front-End Programmer'),
            ( 955, 'Android Programmer'),
            ( 957, 'iOS Programmer'),
            ( 961, 'Back-End Programmer'),
            ( 962, 'Fullstack Programmer'),
            ( 971, 'System Architect'),
    )),
)

#Thus, we need dictionary/set

T4 = {}
def main():
    for k, v in NAMEDTUPLE_ROLES:
        for k1, v1 in v:
            T4.update ( {k1:v1}  )
    print (T4[961]) # will display 'Back-End Programmer'
    # print (T4) # will display all list of dictionary

main()
```

Answer (score -5):

Python 3. Allocate any field to the dictionary as the required index for the dictionary, I used 'name'.

```
import collections

Town = collections.namedtuple("Town", "name population coordinates capital state_bird")

town_list = []

town_list.append(Town('Town 1', '10', '10.10', 'Capital 1', 'Turkey'))
town_list.append(Town('Town 2', '11', '11.11', 'Capital 2', 'Duck'))

town_dictionary = {t.name: t for t in town_list}
```

Comment: Not helpful as you know name is there. it should be a blind method