# Python - How to convert a list in a list of dicts

Tags: python

I am using a custom MariaDB connector to retrieve some data from a DB.

Whenever I execute a `SELECT` query, like:

`cursor.execute(SOME_SELECT_QUERY)`

That returns an object with type:  `<class 'mariadb.connection.cursor'>`

So I tried to convert it to a list with:

`results = list(cursor)`

So if I print the content of `results`, this is the result:

```
[mariadb.Row(record_id=440, chr='chr13'] [mariadb.Row(record_id=449, chr='chr13')]
```

And I would like to have something like this (a list of dicts):

```
[{'record_id': 440, 'chr': 'chr13'}, {'record_id': 449, 'chr': 'chr13'}]
```

Anyone knows how could I get the desired result in a pythonic way?

Comment: can you please print the value of 
```result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/cursor.html?highlight=row fetchall to get the list of tuples. If you create your cursor with `named_tuple=True`, then you can later convert the named tuples to dicts as follows - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180528/convert-a-namedtuple-into-a-dictionary

Comment: Thank you all, but fetchall() didn't work. And named_tuple was already set to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to pass `dictionary=True` while defining the cursor as below?

```
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work using the MariaDB connector,  only the `named_tuple=True`works but it's not what I need.